# Is there a way for ActiveRecord to return instances of other class than the one find was called?

Tags: activerecord

Let's consider the following example:

```
class Ball < ActiveRecord::Base
  def is_ball?
    true
  end
end

class BlueBall < Ball
  def color
    :blue
  end
end

class RedBall < Ball
  def color
    :red
  end
end
```

When I do `Ball.find(id)`, is it possible to have an instance of `BlueBall` returned?

With `Ball.where(owner: some_user).to_a` could I get an array with `BlueBall` and `RedBall` instances?

---

I am looking for a way to explicitly set an STI by using some column other that `type`.

Comment: You might consider searching around SO for "ActiveRecord inheritance" -- but I think the short answer is, this is a bad use of classic OO inheritance.  AR relies on naming conventions in order to do its magic, and this kind of object model isn't handled well (AFAIK) by AR. What's wrong with using a column like `type` or `color`?  What problem are you trying to solve with STI?

Comment: The only reason I have to avoid the `type` column is that I want to use STI on a couple of tables with a few millions of records each and the migration will be a bitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work if it's possible to rename your classes `Red` and `Blue` instead of `RedBall` and `BlueBall`

```
def Ball < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.inheritance_column = :color

  def ball?
    is_a?(Ball)
  end

end

def Red < Ball
  # Red#color would return 'Red'
end

def Blue < Ball
  # Blue#color would return 'Red'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Looks like ActiveRecord does not support passing a block to transform the inheritance value before instantiating the object.

Comment: I don't think it would - if you'd say want the color to return the object's type on a new object - you could try to override it `def color; super || class.to_s; end`